# Connected Service not in VS2013?

Tags: c#, windows, service

I'm looking to try and add some advertisement to my program and found this article on the MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn284011(v=msads.10).aspx

It has a screenshot of where the Connected Service button should be:

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC689229.jpg))</sub>

But when I look, I don't have one:

[image]

I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit with VS Professional 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshot, it looks like you are using a Desktop Windows Forms or WPF project.  Try creating a Windows Store 8.1 app (File -> New Project. Visual C# -> Store Apps -> Universal Apps).  You should see the "Connected Service.." option under the "Add" menu.